# python argparse different parameters with different number of arguments

Tags: python, argparse

How do I use a different number of parameters for each option?

ex) a.py

```
parser.add_argument('--opt', type=str,choices=['a', 'b', 'c'],help='blah~~~')
```

1. choice : a / parameter : 1

ex)

```
$ python a.py --opt a param
```

2. choice : c / parameter :2

ex)

```
$ python a.py --opt b param1 param2
```

Comment: It's not a direct answer, but if you plan on writing command-line scripts, you should have a look at [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/).

Comment: I see a definition for a '--opt' flag (optionals argument), but nothing for '-a' or '--a'.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the contents.

Comment: It doesn't get you all the way to an answer but [parse_known_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) and [nargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You may add more parameters, one for each a, b, and c and also optional arguments for your params. By using the named parameter nargs='?' you can specify that they are optional and with the default="some value" you ensure it rises no errors. Finally, based on the selected option, a,b or c you will be able to capture the ones you need.

Here's a short usage example:

```
parser.add_argument('x1', type=float, nargs='?', default=0, help='Circ. 1 X-coord')
parser.add_argument('y1', type=float, nargs='?', default=0, help='Circ. 1 Y-coord')
parser.add_argument('r1', type=float, nargs='?', default=70, help='Circ. 1 radius')
parser.add_argument('x2', type=float, nargs='?', default=-6.57, help='Circ. 2 X-coord')
parser.add_argument('y2', type=float, nargs='?', default=7, help='Circ. 2 Y-coord')
parser.add_argument('r2', type=float, nargs='?', default=70, help='Circ. 2 radius')
args = parser.parse_args()

circCoverage(args.x1, args.y1, args.r1, args.x2, args.y2, args.r2)
```

here, if no values are selected, the default ones are used. You can play with this to get what you want.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands), `ArgumentParser.add_subparsers()` method will help you

Check this example

```
>>> # create the top-level parser
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', help='foo help')
>>> subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')
>>>
>>> # create the parser for the "a" command
>>> parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
>>> parser_a.add_argument('bar', type=int, help='bar help')
>>>
>>> # create the parser for the "b" command
>>> parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', help='b help')
>>> parser_b.add_argument('--baz', choices='XYZ', help='baz help')
>>>
>>> # parse some argument lists
>>> parser.parse_args(['a', '12'])
Namespace(bar=12, foo=False)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'b', '--baz', 'Z'])
Namespace(baz='Z', foo=True)
```